# pkg --public-packages unable to find "external" module

Tags: node.js, vercel

I am trying to `pkg` a project on my Mac, but for a Linux target.

The project contains the `npm` module `fs-ext` ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-ext ) which relies on some low-level C++ code that needs to be compiled into `fs-ext.node` on the proper target system for it to work.

`npm install fs-ext` does that but the `fs-ext.node` from my Mac is useless on Linux and vice-versa so I need to "externalize" fs-ext, i.e. keep it outside of my `pkg`ed Linux project and install it "manually" into the `node_modules` folder of the `pkg`ed Linux project after I upload the main executable.

The goal is to have file hierarchy like this on the Linux target:

```
+ my-project-executable
|
+ node modules 
    |
    +--+ fs-ext
           |
           +--+ build
                  |
                  +--+ Release
                         |
                         +--- fs-ext.node
```

Then, the idea is to `require` `fs-ext` "dynamically" in my code:

```
const {flockSync} = require(path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules", "fs-ext", "fs-ext.js"));
```

My hope was that this will "reach outside of" the `pkg` sandbox and execute the `fs-ext.js` code, which in turn will use is C++ compiled code `fs-ext.node` as it sees fit.

My pkg command looks like this:

`pkg . -t node14-macos-x64,node14-linux-x64 --public-packages \"fs-ext\"`

I copy the compiled code from my Mac onto the Linux box to `/var/mm/my-pkged-project/` and there I execute `npm install fs-ext`, which generates the proper fs-ext.node file for Linux.

However, when I execute the `pkg`ed file, it says it can't find `fs-ext.js`:

```
pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1930                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      return wrapper.apply(this.exports, args);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                     ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Error: Cannot find module '/var/mm/my-pkged-project/node_modules/fs-ext/fs-ext.js'
```

Strangely, the file is very much there, it exists at that path.

What am I doing wrong? Can compiled and not-compiled code even be mixed like that? Am I not understanding the `pkg` file system sandbox correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to compile with Docker? It enables multi-architecture builds automatically. Also relevant, what version of node are you running? From the `pkg` README.md file: _Disclaimer: pkg was created for use within containers and is not intended for use in serverless environments._ If you just need to compile to use on the browser, you could try `rollup`, `browserify` or `parcel`.

Comment: @Moa Thanks for your ideas, it's on nodeJS, node v16. I understand what you are suggesting with Docker as a workaround. Though the heart of the matter is: Can you or can you not call external JS code (or .node compiled) by requiring it from the "real" filesystem, outside of the pkg "sandbox" filesystem? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, honestly I couldn't infer that from your actual question. I'm a bit confused because you seem to be mixing node built-in packages with "external" packages whilst talking about execution of a project instead of a "single node file" that may or may not `require` code from another file to be executed. AFAIK, you can only require packages, or parts of it, from the "real" filesystem **if and only if** the files are under the folder/tree hierarchy of the project's root directory or that are available/symlinked globally.

Comment: Maybe you could create a symlink inside your Docker container pointing to a predicate which selects the appropriate dependency with `child_process.exec` based on the OS that's running it?